# Why does the GC appear to fail in recursive functions?

Tags: c#, .net, recursion, garbage-collection

If you run this as is it will execute fairly quick and not eat up memory. If you uncomment bad it will get slow and eventually lock up if not throw out of memory exception.

Why does the GC appear to fail in recursive functions?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Repo
{
    class Program
    {
        static Random rng = new Random(42);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Thread(Main2, 50 * 1024 * 1024).Start(); //Increase stack size
        }
        static void Main2()
        {
            //Bad(0, "test");
            var ls = Good(0, "test");
            while(ls.Any())
            {
                var v = ls.First();
                ls.AddRange(Good(v.Item1, v.Item2));
                ls.RemoveAt(0);
            }
        }
        class Foo
        {
            public byte[] data;
            public Foo(int size) { data = new byte[size]; }
        }
        static List<Tuple<int, string>> Good(int a, string b)
        {
            if (a >= 5000000)
                return new List<Tuple<int, string>>();
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", a);
            var ls = new List<Tuple<int, string>>();
            {
                var data = new byte[rng.Next(1024, 1024 * 20)]; //This line eats up all the memory
                ls.Add(Tuple.Create(a + 1, ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetString(data, 128, 64)));
            }
            return ls;
        }
        static void Bad(int a, string b)
        {
            if (a >= 5000000)
                return;
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", a);
            var ls = new List<Tuple<int, string>>();
            {
                var data = new byte[rng.Next(1024, 1024 * 20)]; //This line eats up all the memory
                ls.Add(Tuple.Create(a+1, ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetString(data, 128, 64)));
            }
            foreach(var v in ls)
            {
                Bad(v.Item1, v.Item2);
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Every recursive call to `Bad()` will keep alive a reference to `v.Item2` because it is being passed to `Bad()`. This will keep alive a reference to `v` and hence `ls`, which means there's a live reference to every `List<Tuple<int, string>>` that was created until such time as the deepest call to `Bad()` returns.

Comment: Recursive methods and the local data go on the execution stack and doesn't get released until the method returns.  You are recursively calling the method over and over again and never returning so the memory isn't being released.  Garbage collection is run on memory objects that usually not part of the execution stack.

Comment: Looks like a good MVCE but you should clarify whether the results were obtained with or without the debugger attached. Also target CPU and versions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The JIT can perform lifetime analysis and determine that local variables can be collected before they go out of scope, so it's not that your array *must* be rooted by its stack frame.

**However**, when running in a debug build or under the debugger, the GC is more conservative (in case you want to inspect values during your debugging session). Run a release build outside of the debugger and you'll see a much more gradual memory increase that can be explained by the living references to your list and tuples in the recursive call.

Comment: Bingo we have a winner. I tried this and you're absolutely right. Although I don't think it CAN show me the data bc it is completely out of scope I have noticed bad runs fine if I run it in release. I like to add that for the main project we were running in debug bc we were debugging it a lot and can't really do so in release which fixes this.

Answer (score 5):

In the `Good()` version, you allocate `ls` once, add a reasonably small Tuple to it, and `Good()` returns to the caller.

In the `Bad()` version, the initial invocation of `Bad()` spawns many recursive calls to `Bad()`, which in turn can spawn many of their own recursive calls. You keep creating new instances of `ls` in each iteration of `Bad()`, to which you keep adding new Tuples. Your memory profiler should show you that you have many more bytes used by the type `List<Tuple<int, string>>` in the `Bad()` case. It's not the `byte[] data`, which should indeed go out of scope.

The references to `ls` cannot be collected until a given recursive call completes.

Comment: The profiler says its **Foo**. It doesn't appear to be the list as you suggested. I ran this piece of code to give me an idea of how much memory list eats up and it wasnt much.  https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2785d41cb92fb9a9f0faa18c518d0beb

Comment: You're right. For the repo this profiler shows me memory is being eaten but not how (I get an empty list. Although it says I use > 1gb which is more than the list snippet I linked). I didnt realized I accidentally hit undo too many times and didn't include foo. The main app which I profiled it showed a 3rd party HTML lib was the problem (what I called foo) dispute it not being in scope during recursion.

Answer (score 2):

The GC won't clean up objects that are still referenced and with your recursive chain the objects you're creating aren't de-referenced until the recursive method hits its end condition and starts percolating back to the first call. So essentially you are seeing a good example of how the GC won't cleanup anything it views as still in use (such as ancestors in a recursive chain).

If you are curious about how .NET and memory handling is done in depth you can try using a tool like the .NET Memory Profiler (http://memprofiler.com/) or similar tool.

Comment: Are you saying there is still a reference to Foo when I hit the foreach loop in bad? Because that shouldn't be and the profiler makes it look like its the case

Comment: Unless I'm blind, I don't see `Foo` actually being used or referenced anywhere in your code.

Comment: forget foo, everything created in your `bad` function (ls and data and the stack) is not released until the huge recursion unwinds. Which is never going to happen since you run out of memory before it completes

Comment: ls,data, .. in each stack frame are different. You are trying to create 5000000 ls and 5000000 data,.... and hold them all in memory at once

Comment: @acidzombie24 The main take-away from this isn't a problem with Foo but that as soon as you call the Bad method, it starts a recursive chain where it's unable to cleanup any data in the chain until the recursion is finished and starts returning up the chain. You are simply running out of memory before that can happen.

One way to think of it is that the entire chain of recursive calls have to be able to fit in memory at the same time or else you'll run into this since GC is unable to cleanup anything in the chain until it hits the end at which point it can cleanup as it percolates up.

Comment: Like I said is it running out of memory because of the array or because of the list? In another comment I linked a piece of code. I had an array of 500K list and the memory was nowhere near as bad as `bad()`. `data` should be unreachable and cleaned up